# How can I receive a file using PHP?

Tags: php, html

So say I have a file, example.txt. How can I, using `$_POST`, take that file using HTML/JavaScript and edit it using PHP?

I apologize if this question is too broad, I'm a beginner so please tell me how I can be more vivid.

Comment: Show us what you tried?

Comment: "tell me how I can be more vivid." Your question is crystal clear. The problem is that you're asking for *a lot* of content that already exists all over the web in *many, many* tutorials. Give one of them a shot. If you get stuck while working though it, we could help you though it - but asking for an entire tutorial is, as you suspect, too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form and make sure you include the enctype tag ..

```
<form method="post" action="form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And then in your PHP ...

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```